# how to use controller make submit button visible or invisible in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this model class

```
public string OPTION_NAME { get; set; }
public string OPTION_VALUE { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult IndexRegistrationGuideline()
{
    //return View();
    IEnumerable<OPTIONS> options = _optionsService.GetOptions().Where(opt => opt.OPTION_NAME == "options_registration_guideline");
    return View(options);
}
```

From the controller above, it checks the table if the field where **OPTION_NAME == "options_registration_guideline** is more than one record, the Add New button in the view below is visible else if it's just one record, the Add New button is hidden

**View**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("CreateGender")" class="btn bg-blue">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
    Add New
</a>
```

Please how do i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is strongly typed to a collection. So you can check the count of the view model object, which is the collection and conditionally render the link.

You can use the `Count()` method to get the count of items and use that in your if condition

```
@model IEnumerable<OPTIONS>
<h2>My view</h2>

@if (Model.Count() > 1)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("CreateGender")" class="btn bg-blue">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        Add New
    </a>
}
```

The above code will render the link if the count is greater than 1. else it does not render the link ( which includes count==1 condition and count == 0 condition )